# Adding TextField and its listerner in LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx, textfield

I am new to the UI elements in LibGdx. I need to add a text field in my Android App which is being built in LibGdx framework. Please point me a good example of doing it without using a Stage.

So far I have not used a Stage in any of my apps. Is it mandatory to use Stage to use TextField and its listenerer ?

All these I am trying to find is just because I need to have the keyboard and its flexibility in capturing the text in TextField.

Please

Comment: Stages and Actors (TextField is an Actor) are part of scene2d. A stage is a 2d scene graph with a hierarchy of actors (from the docs). Actors are meant to be added to a Stage and "act"ed on accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextField` is part of scene2d API, so it's required to use `Stage`.

Stage receives input events and it fires them on the appropriate actors.

---

If your application needs to ask the user for a string, e.g a user name or a password, you can use `Gdx.input.getTextInput(...)`

You can check [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Simple-text-input) more about `Gdx.input.getTextInput(...)`

Comment: Was about to integrate `stage` reading your https://stackoverflow.com/a/45018087/866333, but this means I don't have to.