# Using TextField with LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am working on an Android game with LibGDX and would like to implement two `TextField`s to login to a server.

As far as I know I need to use [`Stage`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html) to add a `TextField` as an [`Actor`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) like this:

```
this.stage = new Stage();
TextField txtf = new TextField("", mSkin);
//...
stage.addActor(txtf);
// And then set the stage as InputProcessor
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this.stage);
```

But I already have a custom `InputHandler` which implements `InputProcessor`. I don't really know how I can handle a `TextField` with my `InputHandler`.

I have created my `TextField` in my `InputHandler` like this:

```
public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {

public InputHandler(float ratioWidth, float ratioHeight, GameWorld world) {
        this.world = world;
        this.player = world.getPlayer();
        this.ratioWidth = ratioWidth;
        this.ratioHeight = ratioHeight;

        //...

        this.usernameTextField = new TextField("", AssetLoader.defaultSkin);
        this.usernameTextField.setPosition(24,73);
        this.usernameTextField.setSize(88, 14);
        this.passwordTextField = new TextField("", AssetLoader.defaultSkin);
        this.passwordTextField.setPosition(24, 102);
        this.passwordTextField.setSize(88, 14);

        this.actors.add(this.usernameTextField);
        this.actors.add(this.passwordTextField);
    }
```

And then I have a method in my `InputHandler` that can get the `TextField` for the `GameRenderer`:

```
public ArrayList<Actor> getActors() { return this.actors; }
```

And this is my `GameRenderer`:

```
public class GameRenderer {

    public GameRenderer(GameWorld world) {
        this.world = world;

        //...
    }

    //...

    private void drawLogUI() {

        for(Actor a : ((InputHandler) Gdx.input.getInputProcessor()).getActors()){
            a.draw(batcher, 1);
        }

        //...
    }

    public void render(float delta) {

        // Initialisation
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(32/255.0f, 72/255.0f, 132/255.0f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batcher.begin();
        batcher.enableBlending();

        //...

        drawLogUI();

        //...

        batcher.end();
    }

    //...

}
```

`TextField`s are rendering correctly but I can't do anything with them, keyboard doesn't show up, etc. Can someone explain how I can use them in my project ?

Comment: You can use two input processors at the same time using an InputMultiplexer https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html

Comment: Same result, when i use a InputMultiplexer and add my Stage to it, TextField don't do anything.

Comment: `Scene2d` without stage ? why are you drawing by `drawLogUI()`

Comment: I recently learned libGDX by this tutorial : [Kilobolt tutorial](http://www.kilobolt.com/zombie-bird-tutorial-flappy-bird-remake.html) And that's what they do, it work pretty well so i did it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that you need to use `Stage` and `TextField` for your requirement, you created `TextField` but not adding to stage so you're not using scene2d(stage, actor, textfield..)

Tutorial that you following, don't have stage so he is using `InputProcessor` for his requirement.

```
TextField usernameTextField = new TextField("", AssetLoader.defaultSkin);
usernameTextField.setPosition(24,73);
usernameTextField.setSize(88, 14);

stage.add(usernameTextField);            // <-- Actor now on stage 
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Inside `render()` method call

```
stage.draw();
stage.act();
```